# How do you create such an animated GIF via Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, export, animation

Is it possible to create such kind of GIF via *Mathematica*?

[image: animation]

Comment: It is possible...

Comment: As @Chenminqi answered, it is possible. But before anyone actually show you the ways, it would be better you show the effort you have made. So what have you tried?

Comment: @Silvia Writing code..

Comment: a little bit related: [Morphing a “sheet of paper” into a torus](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42593/5478)

Comment: @Silvia I created the GIF via Geogebra

Comment: @LCFactorization I mean you might want to include a description (even better with some code) on what you have tried in solving the problem in **Mathematica**, so instead of accomplishing your work from scratch, people can see the specific point where ***you*** are stuck in, so they might have a better chance giving more specific and effective answers. That would fit more in the spirit of the site, also more polite for people who are reading and trying to answer your questions. :)

Comment: @Silvia  sounds reasonable but that would limit the diversity of the answers. Different people may be comfortable with different approaches.

Comment: @Silvia the mathematics I used in Geogebra is a little more complicated than the answer below. E.g., I used 3D rotation matrix and parallel projection to obtain the parametric equations for the first step; then I used a complex computation in Descartes frame rather than polarized frame to obtain the parametric curve for the second step. I am surprised that the implementation can actually be simplified so much in mathematica

Comment: @LCFactorization Hey there, if you're interested, you can drop me an email(please see [my profile](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/17/silvia) for addr) for more discussions!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_, θ_] = 
  RotationTransform[θ, {1, 0, 1}, {5 Pi, 0, 5 Pi}][{x, 
     0, -((10 Pi)/6) Sin[x] + 5 Pi}][[{1, 3}]];
p1 = ParametricPlot[{x, x}, {x, -10 Pi, 10 Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10 Pi, 10 Pi}, {-10 Pi, 10 Pi}, {-10 Pi, 10 Pi}}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, Axes -> True];
n = 7;
g[a_] := Evaluate[
   t^(1/n) (5 a π^2)/(1 + 5 a π) + (1 - t^(1/n)) (
       10 a π)/(1 + 5 a π) /. 
     t -> Rescale[a, {0.002, 2 Pi}, {0, 1}] // Simplify];
t = Pi;
Manipulate[
 If[var < Pi + 0.0025, 
  Show[p1, ParametricPlot[f[x, var], {x, -10 Pi, 10 Pi}]], 
  Show[p1, PolarPlot[
     5 Pi + 1/(var - t) - 
      5/3 π Sin[(2 Pi)/(2*g[var - t]/10) θ], {θ, -g[
        var - t], g[var - t]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-10 Pi, 10 Pi}, {-10 Pi, 10 Pi}}, 
     ImageSize -> 300] /. 
    Line[data___] :> 
     Translate[Line[data], {-(1/(var - t)), 0}]]], {var, 0, 
  2 Pi + Pi}]
```

[image: enter code here]

The best way is take suitable discrete points of var artificially, not let var change uniform.

**Update 1**
A better solution from other people.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{1 - 1/y + 
    Cos[θ] (2 + 1/y - Sin[(10 θ)/y]), 
   Sin[θ] (2 + 1/y - 
      Sin[(10 θ)/y])}, {θ, -π y, π y}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {y, 0.01, 1}]
```

Comment: Why is it so slow at the end, when linking the two points to create a closed path?

Comment: Related link, http://blog.csdn.net/stereohomology/article/details/41625867

Answer (score 7):

Here's a start, the 2nd transformation is tricky for me.

```
data = Table[{i, 0.1 Sin[100 i] + 0.7, 0}, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}];
gr = Graphics3D[{Thick, Red, Line@data}, Boxed -> False];
Manipulate[Graphics3D[
  {If[t < 0.1 Pi, {Dashed, Blue, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}]}, {}],
   Arrow[{{0.5, 0, 0}, {0.5, 1, 0}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0.5, 0}, {1, 0.5, 0}}], 
   GeometricTransformation[{Thick, Red, Line@data}, 
    RotationTransform[t, {1, 1, 0}]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Boxed -> False, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> Top], {t, 0, 0.99 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: @hhh I cheated and used [LiceCAP](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/)

Comment: And now after getting angry I got the solution also to the other method [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Manipulate-and-Animate-in-Mathematica/answer/Mark-Barton-1?__snids__=859179407&__nsrc__=2) -- actually it is super easy also that way. So now two methods, hurray :D