# Map points on a square onto a Torus

Tags: plotting, graphics, coordinate-transformation

I would like to create a 3D torus plot from a 2D graphic. This 2D original plot is a bit complex, and I haven't a clue how could transform it to a torus.

The below code, from [this article posted on Wolfram MathSource](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/9281/), performs a random walk under certain conditions. It depends on the [NetLogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) software and the included [NetLogo *Mathematica* link package](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/mathematica.html).

```
StartShot = 
  ArrayPlot[NLGetPatches["covername"], 
   ColorRules ->  {"arable_land" -> Brown, 
     "forests" -> Darker[Green]}, Frame -> False, 
   DataRange -> {{-400, 0}, {0, 400}}];

startingpoints = NLReport["map last [path] of persons"];
agents = ListPlot[startingpoints, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Small], White], AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Axes -> None, Frame -> False, DataRange -> {{-400, 0}, {0, 400}}];

paths = NLReport["[path] of persons"];
lineplot = 
  ListLinePlot[paths, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> None, Frame -> False, 
   DataRange -> {{-400, 0}, {0, 400}}, PlotStyle -> White];

Show[StartShot, lineplot, agents, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image: original pic]

The `lineplot` and `agents` plots are from coordinates, but the `startshot` is from `ArrayPlot`, and therefore is a graphic which doesn't directly represent any coordinates that could be transformed onto the torus.

My aim is to create a visualisation like the one shown below, which was presented by [Vitaliy Kaurov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13/vitaliy-kaurov) in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57571/) to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57561/2d-random-walk-within-a-bounded-area) related question about random walks. However, I wasn't able to apply his approach to my case.

[image: content on torus]

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you do want to create a random walk on the surface of a torus?

Comment: I would like to spread the upper image to a torus by wrapping or coordinate transformations.

Comment: Have a look at this question on [wolfram community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/176327?p_p_auth=ek6XdJL3).

Comment: I allowed myself to suggest an edit to the title of your question. I hope you don't mind

Comment: I approved it, thank you.

Comment: related: [Morphing a “sheet of paper” into a torus](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42493/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get your texture, then:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]},
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 30], 
 Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}]]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 2 #5} &), 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Mesh -> None, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Or define `mytexture =` and insert the graphic of your star map.  Then:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[u]},
    {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 30], 
 Texture[mytexture]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &), 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Mesh -> None, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's almost perfect, I only cannot correct those white bands, the forest was done by slight modifications:
`code`
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (3 + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (3 + Cos[u]), 
  Sin[u]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Specularity[White, 30], Texture[boxworld]], 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &), Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> All]
`code`
I don't understand the #4 #5 links by the way. :/