NMinimize too slow
A few days ago, while I was learning more about NMinimize[], in the Applications section I was intrigued by Trajectory Optimization. Once I understood the basic idea I tried to apply it to a toroidal surface, that is:
{n, r, R} = {30, 2, 4};

f[i_] = {x[i], y[i], z[i]};
g[{x_, y_, z_}] = (R - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2 - r^2;
h[u_, v_] = {(R + r Cos[u]) Cos[v], (R + r Cos[u]) Sin[v], r Sin[u]};

cns = {Table[Sqrt[Total[(f[i] - f[i - 1])^2]] <= l/n, {i, n}],
       Table[g[f[i]] == 0, {i, 0, n}],
       f[0] == h[0, 0], f[n] == h[3π/5, 6π/5]};

pts = Table[f[i], {i, 0, n}];
vars = Join[Flatten[pts], {l}];
sol = NMinimize[{l, cns}, vars][[2]];

Show[ParametricPlot3D[h[u, v], {u, 0, 2π}, {v, 0, 2π}],
     Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts /. sol]}]]

where, unlike the problem in the documentation, not being able to use Method -> "DifferenceOfConvex" the waiting time for a response is as long as 4 minutes:


l -> 10.4915

Interestingly, the same result can be obtained in a few seconds by:
FindMinimum[{l, cns}, vars][[2]]

but unfortunately it's enough to choose f[n] == h[4π/5, 7π/5] to get $l=8.37329$ with NMinimize[] and $l=13.8449$ with FindMinimum[], so the latter is not useful to me. :(

If you were wondering, I'm using 14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)


Question: Is there a way to get the same results as NMinimize[] more quickly?



Please explain a bit about the purpose of the code, otherwise it'll be hard to help. The question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site. Anyway, if I have to guess, are you looking for this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103624/1871

For the present problem, FindMinimum is much faster than NMinimize.

So, what's the goal? Understand why NMinimize is slow, or adjust NMinimize to make it faster, or simply find faster method for the task, or something else?

sol = NMinimize[{l, a, b, c}, vars, Method -> "NelderMead"][[2]] results in less than 5 minutes for me. Up to the picture, the solution does not look optimal. This answers part 2 of your question.

"will FindMinimum[] and NMinimize[] always give the same solution?" That's easy: No. Nor is either guaranteed to give the global minimum. If you can start FindMinimum near the optimal solution, then it will usually find it (approximately).

You wrote " Is there a way to get the same results as NMinimize[] more quickly?". It recalls to me an anecdote.. A seller to a buyer: :"We have high quality and low prices. What do you prefer?"

This is an extended comment.
I would refer the OP to the excellent answer by @NikiEstner
Using the geodesicFindMin function from that answer:
geodesicFindMin[{p1_, p2_}, nPts_ : 25] := 
 Module[{approximatePts, optimizeOffset, optimizeOffsets, direction, 
   normal, pathLength, optimalPath, interpolations, len, solution}, 
  direction = p2 - p1;
  normal = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}} . direction;
  approximatePts = 
   Join[{p1}, 
    Table[p1 + i*direction/(nPts + 1) + optimizeOffset[i]*normal, {i, 
      nPts}], {p2}];
  pathLength = Total[Norm /@ Differences[torus /@ approximatePts]];
  {len, solution} = 
   Quiet[FindMinimum[pathLength, 
     Table[{optimizeOffset[i], 0}, {i, nPts}]]];
  optimalPath = approximatePts /. solution;
  interpolations = 
   ListInterpolation[#, {{0, 1}}] & /@ Transpose[optimalPath];
  Function[t, #[t] & /@ interpolations]]

Defining the torus of interest
torus[{u_, v_}] := {(4 + 2 Cos[u]) Cos[v], (4 + 2 Cos[u]) Sin[v], 
  2 Sin[u]}

Applying geodesicFindMin
Show[ParametricPlot3D[torus[{u, v}], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[
   torus[geodesicFindMin[{{0, 0}, {3 \[Pi]/5, 6 \[Pi]/5}}, 50][
     t]]], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Green, 
   Point[torus /@ {{0, 0}, {3 \[Pi]/5, 6 \[Pi]/5}}]}]]



Approximating length of geodesic
y[t_] := 
 torus[geodesicFindMin[{{0, 0}, {3 \[Pi]/5, 6 \[Pi]/5}}, 30][t]]
NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + D[y[t], t] . D[y[t], t]], {t, 0, 1}]

-> 13.379
Comments

one can increase the number of points and reassess
I note the variety of answers for l with the  different methods. I note this is based on the discretization and way path is determined. So, though in the above it is longer the some of the other minimizations it is a different method for path creation and I leave to other uses to debate which is more accurate or provide a result from numerical integration of non-closed form analytic result

I apologise for any errors and wish all users a safe and peaceful time during this period.
Καλά Χριστούγεννα to the OP.

If I correctly understand it ,  the result 10.4915 of NMinimize in my answer  is better than the result 13.379 of geodesicFindMin.

I do not believe you have read the answer in sufficient depth. Nonetheless, the naive observation that one number is smaller than another and drawing the conclusion the smaller one is better as the word Minimum is somehow sought fails to  appreciate that one method may follow a surface better than another and yield a more accurate result. If the answer was actually read this would have been understood. Others can form there own objective opinion.

@user64494  The original question using (f[i] - f[i - 1])^2 such Euclidean distance means that the path not fully on the surface, I think that is why the min result is smaller then the path which on the surface.

Behold, we are only a few days (or weeks?) away from getting GeodesicCurve in v14.2 :)

@Domen neat! Look forward to it if I can get update.

@cvgmt: Please ground your claim "The original question using (f[i] - f[i - 1])^2  such Euclidean distance means that the path not fully on the surface,"

@user64494 I think it's quite clear from the code. the constraint Table[g[f[i]] == 0, {i, 0, n}] has only forced the discrete points (rather than the curves passing through the points!) to be on the surface. And Sqrt[Total[(f[i] - f[i - 1])^2]] is only measuring the straightline distance between the points. Given the grid isn't too dense (it's only n=30), I can imagine some inaccuracy will be introduced. (The l/n part is also a bit questionable. ) But probably we still need more careful numeric checking.

@xzczd: Sorry, the difference between 10.4915 and  13.379 is too large for your attempt of the explanation.

@xzczd: Asso see that Wike article for the definition of the length of a curve.

@user64494 Yeah, that's why I said we proabably need more careful numeric checking. I can't think out a good enough way for checking at the moment, but I should admit that the visualization seems to suggest 10.4915 is reliable enough.

@xzczd: Also  Encyclopedia of Mathematics says "The length of a simple arc is the least upper bound of the lengths of the broken lines inscribed in this arc".

@user64494 "The length of a simple arc is the least upper bound of the lengths of the broken lines inscribed in this arc" Yeah, this means the actual arc length is larger, isn't it?

Differential equations for geodesic curves are know and, in the case of a torus, given by Section 5 of http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf
eq1 = u'[v] == (R + r Cos[u[v]]) Sqrt[(R + r Cos[u[v]])^2 - g^2]/(r g)

However, NDSolve has difficulty with this equation when the argument of Sqrt vanishes.  In this case, the corresponding second-order equation works better.
{r, R} = {2, 4};
eq2 = ApplySides[Simplify[D[#^2, v]/(2 u'[v]), Trig -> False] &, eq1]
(* (u''[v] == ((2 + Cos[u[v]]) (-32 + g^2 - 32 Cos[u[v]] - 
    8 Cos[u[v]]^2) Sin[u[v]])/g^2 *)

Values of g corresponding to the boundary conditions specified in the question can be located quickly by.
f = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq2, u[0] == 0, eq1 /. v -> 0}, 
    u[6 Pi/5] - 3 Pi/5, {v, 0, 6 Pi/5}, g];
Plot[f[g], {g, -6, 6}, AxesLabel -> {g, "f"}, LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Black}]


For Abs[g] > 6, there are no real solutions.  Thus, there are three geodesics satisfying the boundary conditions.  (The crossing at g = 0 is spurious, arising from 1/g in eq1 and eq2.)  The geodesic for g near 2 is given by
FindRoot[f[g], {g, 2, 4}] // First
(* g -> 2.11936 *)

NDSolveValue[{eq2, u[0] == 0, eq1 /. v -> 0} /. %, 
    {(R + r Cos[u[v]]) Cos[v], (R + r Cos[u[v]]) Sin[v], r Sin[u[v]]}, 
    {v, 0, 6 Pi/5}];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[h[u, v], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}, LabelStyle -> {10, Bold, Black},
    PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[.6]}, MeshStyle -> Opacity[.3]], 
    ParametricPlot3D[%, {v, 0, 6 Pi/5}, PlotStyle -> Blue]]


This is the same geodesic obtained by ubdpqn.  Its length is give by
ArcLength[%%, {v, 0, 6 Pi/5}]
(* 13.3268 *)

The other two geodesics are obtained similarly.  For g -> -2.31269 the geodesic curves under the torus and has length 20.0163.  (The "hidden" portion of the geodesic is shown with a fainter curve.)

For g -> -3.26091 the geodesic also curves under the torus and has length 20.5084.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The command (with f[n] == h[3π/5, 6π/5] in your code)
sol = NMinimize[{l, a, b, c}, vars, Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 200}]


{11.7771, {x[0] -> 6., y[0] -> 0, z[0] -> 0, x[1] -> 5.9626,  y[1] -> 0.0819059, z[1] -> 0.382104, x[2] -> 5.85199,  y[2] -> 0.165989, z[2] -> 0.749265, x[3] -> 5.67319,  y[3] -> 0.256933, z[3] -> 1.08671, x[4] -> 5.43362,  y[4] -> 0.352309, z[4] -> 1.38271, x[5] -> 5.14117,  y[5] -> 0.440714, z[5] -> 1.62922, x[6] -> 4.80341,  y[6] -> 0.501357, z[6] -> 1.81987, x[7] -> 4.43237,  y[7] -> 0.526814, z[7] -> 1.94553, x[8] -> 4.0434, y[8] -> 0.530126, z[8] -> 1.99848, x[9] -> 3.65167, y[9] -> 0.518578,  z[9] -> 1.97556, x[10] -> 3.2734, y[10] -> 0.483055,  z[10] -> 1.87678, x[11] -> 2.92817, y[11] -> 0.406957,  z[11] -> 1.70608, x[12] -> 2.63886, y[12] -> 0.27113,  z[12] -> 1.47814, x[13] -> 2.41445, y[13] -> 0.0776171,  z[13] -> 1.22065, x[14] -> 2.24254, y[14] -> -0.166692,  z[14] -> 0.965949, x[15] -> 2.09726, y[15] -> -0.464286,  z[15] -> 0.755137, x[16] -> 1.93793, y[16] -> -0.787095,  z[16] -> 0.598558, x[17] -> 1.73999, y[17] -> -1.1146,  z[17] -> 0.510979, x[18] -> 1.49141, y[18] -> -1.41593,  z[18] -> 0.472005, x[19] -> 1.20156, y[19] -> -1.67878,  z[19] -> 0.503735, x[20] -> 0.868335, y[20] -> -1.88336,  z[20] -> 0.538646, x[21] -> 0.511455, y[21] -> -2.03134,  z[21] -> 0.608262, x[22] -> 0.144317, y[22] -> -2.12555,  z[22] -> 0.710463, x[23] -> -0.237644, y[23] -> -2.15203,  z[23] -> 0.795717, x[24] -> -0.601028, y[24] -> -2.15432,  z[24] -> 0.943595, x[25] -> -0.95092, y[25] -> -2.14215,  z[25] -> 1.12106, x[26] -> -1.29509, y[26] -> -2.12425,  z[26] -> 1.30904, x[27] -> -1.64737, y[27] -> -2.07502,  z[27] -> 1.47512, x[28] -> -2.00311, y[28] -> -2.00576,  z[28] -> 1.62545, x[29] -> -2.36413, y[29] -> -1.97763,  z[29] -> 1.77699, x[30] -> -2.73607, y[30] -> -1.98787,  z[30] -> 1.90211, l -> 11.7771}}

and a warning (not an error).
Show[ParametricPlot3D[h[u, v], {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts /. sol1[[2]]]}]]


whereas
sol1 = FindMinimum[{l, a, b, c}, vars]


{13.5379, {x[0] -> 6., y[0] -> 0., z[0] -> 0., x[1] -> 5.95247,  y[1] -> 0.141759, z[1] -> -0.425775, x[2] -> 5.81222,  y[2] -> 0.281313, z[2] -> -0.831355, x[3] -> 5.58619,  y[3] -> 0.416723, z[3] -> -1.19771, x[4] -> 5.28546,  y[4] -> 0.546573, z[4] -> -1.50809, x[5] -> 4.92452,  y[5] -> 0.670219, z[5] -> -1.74907, x[6] -> 4.5203,  y[6] -> 0.788009, z[6] -> -1.91147, x[7] -> 4.09084,  y[7] -> 0.90145, z[7] -> -1.99105, x[8] -> 3.65365, y[8] -> 1.01327, z[8] -> -1.98911, x[9] -> 3.22377, y[9] -> 1.12723,  z[9] -> -1.91258, x[10] -> 2.8116, y[10] -> 1.24756,  z[10] -> -1.77374, x[11] -> 2.42097, y[11] -> 1.37763,  z[11] -> -1.58901, x[12] -> 2.04823, y[12] -> 1.51808,  z[12] -> -1.37694, x[13] -> 1.68345, y[13] -> 1.66453,  z[13] -> -1.15528, x[14] -> 1.31407, y[14] -> 1.80636,  z[14] -> -0.938302, x[15] -> 0.929799, y[15] -> 1.92741,  z[15] -> -0.735024, x[16] -> 0.526752, y[16] -> 2.00896,  z[16] -> -0.54917, x[17] -> 0.109027, y[17] -> 2.03356,  z[17] -> -0.380231, x[18] -> -0.312243, y[18] -> 1.98832,  z[18] -> -0.224912, x[19] -> -0.721438, y[19] -> 1.867,  z[19] -> -0.0783557, x[20] -> -1.10156, y[20] -> 1.67056,  z[20] -> 0.0650275, x[21] -> -1.4373, y[21] -> 1.40675,  z[21] -> 0.211048, x[22] -> -1.71773, y[22] -> 1.08864,  z[22] -> 0.365336, x[23] -> -1.93851, y[23] -> 0.732499,  z[23] -> 0.532843, x[24] -> -2.10323, y[24] -> 0.35491,  z[24] -> 0.717055, x[25] -> -2.22333, y[25] -> -0.030463,  z[25] -> 0.9188, x[26] -> -2.31612, y[26] -> -0.415652,  z[26] -> 1.13481, x[27] -> -2.40078, y[27] -> -0.79945,  z[27] -> 1.35655, x[28] -> -2.49367, y[28] -> -1.18591,  z[28] -> 1.57023, x[29] -> -2.60469, y[29] -> -1.58082,  z[29] -> 1.75828, x[30] -> -2.73607, y[30] -> -1.98787,  z[30] -> 1.90211, l -> 13.5379}}

Addition. Much better
sol = NMinimize[{l, a, b, c}, vars]


{10.4915, {x[0] -> 6., y[0] -> 0, z[0] -> 0, x[1] -> 5.97286,  y[1] -> -0.1432, z[1] -> 0.317898, x[2] -> 5.89222,  y[2] -> -0.285119, z[2] -> 0.627185, x[3] -> 5.76044,  y[3] -> -0.424567, z[3] -> 0.91957, x[4] -> 5.5813,  y[4] -> -0.560532, z[4] -> 1.18739, x[5] -> 5.35993,  y[5] -> -0.692263, z[5] -> 1.42391, x[6] -> 5.1025,  y[6] -> -0.819351, z[6] -> 1.62361, x[7] -> 4.81598,  y[7] -> -0.941787, z[7] -> 1.78241, x[8] -> 4.50779,  y[8] -> -1.06001, z[8] -> 1.89794, x[9] -> 4.18537,  y[9] -> -1.17492, z[9] -> 1.96964, x[10] -> 3.85568,  y[10] -> -1.28783, z[10] -> 1.99894, x[11] -> 3.5247,  y[11] -> -1.40036, z[11] -> 1.98923, x[12] -> 3.19691,  y[12] -> -1.51423, z[12] -> 1.94576, x[13] -> 2.87481,  y[13] -> -1.63086, z[13] -> 1.87543, x[14] -> 2.55869,  y[14] -> -1.75095, z[14] -> 1.78628, x[15] -> 2.24674,  y[15] -> -1.87394, z[15] -> 1.68695, x[16] -> 1.93559,  y[16] -> -1.99761, z[16] -> 1.58599, x[17] -> 1.6212,  y[17] -> -2.11789, z[17] -> 1.49116, x[18] -> 1.30001,  y[18] -> -2.22918, z[18] -> 1.40897, x[19] -> 0.969953,  y[19] -> -2.3251, z[19] -> 1.34444, x[20] -> 0.631,  y[20] -> -2.39948, z[20] -> 1.30109, x[21] -> 0.285184,  y[21] -> -2.44756, z[21] -> 1.28104, x[22] -> -0.0639793,  y[22] -> -2.46678, z[22] -> 1.28521, x[23] -> -0.412429,  y[23] -> -2.45735, z[23] -> 1.31342, x[24] -> -0.756628,  y[24] -> -2.4222, z[24] -> 1.36435, x[25] -> -1.09448,  y[25] -> -2.36646, z[25] -> 1.43541, x[26] -> -1.42586,  y[26] -> -2.29653, z[26] -> 1.52258, x[27] -> -1.75256,  y[27] -> -2.21895, z[27] -> 1.62032, x[28] -> -2.07767,  y[28] -> -2.13934, z[28] -> 1.72165, x[29] -> -2.40461,  y[29] -> -2.06164, z[29] -> 1.81846, x[30] -> -2.73607,  y[30] -> -1.98787, z[30] -> 1.90211, l -> 10.4915}}

in approximately 15 minutes. Corollary: FindMinimum is faster, NMinimise is better.

It would be useful to solve that problem in Maple. However, it is winter time ... Maybe, I 'll return to it later.

Despite your words, for f[n] == h[4π/5, 7π/5] the FindMinimum command finds 8.37329, whereas sol = NMinimize[{l, a, b, c}, vars,    Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 200}] produces 20.9106 in 25 minutes.

In this case the command NMinimize[{l, a, b, c}, vars] produces the same 8.37329 in 10 minutes.

1.This is potentially useful extended comment but is not an answer. 2.It provides the results of the various approaches and describes the approx times. "Copy and paste" of Mma output is a minimal effort approach. A succinct table of method, result, time would improve clarity rather than tediously looking through output that any user can generate for themselves. 3.It is unclear (apart from cosmetics) what the point of a single plot when multiple methods were used 4. A minor English  language semantic pt: the use of term "corollary"  without a preceding explicit conclusion is questionable.

@ubpdqn: 4. See N. Bourbaky, Éléments de mathématique concerning the usage of the corollary termin.

https://i.sstatic.net/UDTpKgCE.png …OK user64494 and @ubpdqn you see, I'm not a native speaker so cannot comment much about English part, but you know we have https://english.stackexchange.com/ so you guys may consider asking a question there (if you believe you really want to discuss this).

@xzczd thank you for link. I will look at when I can. My point was not a criticism of  language skills. I cannot speak Cantonese/Mandarin/Russian and countless other languages. My point would have been made even for English natives: it was a semantic point. Presumably, the reply directing me to French literature relates to that (unless it was pure distraction). And of course, I accept I may be wrong.
