# Plotting a graph on a torus and another surfaces

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to figure out how to plot a graph on a surface. My goal is to represent a planar embedding of $ K_5$ in a torus. I have encountered [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26749/plotting-a-contour-on-a-torus), where you can find an explanation how to plot a contour on a torus. However, I'm not very keen on representing a graph as a function.

I was thinking that it might be a good idea to first embed the graph into a square and then "gluing" this square into a torus. I'm not sure how to apply this idea.

I will appreciate any hints

Comment: closely related: [103215](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103215/5478), [103624](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103624/5478), [42493](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42493/5478)

Comment: Thanks for the hint - I'm wondering if there's any way to do that using functions like `GraphPlot3d[]` instead of just plotting curves