# Want to plot a mapping from the interval [0,1] to the unit circle

Tags: plotting

i´d like to plot a interpretation of a map that transforms the interval [0,1] to the unit circle.

And also the same with a rectangle that is transformed to a cylinder which  then is transformed into the torus.

Unfortunately i have no idea how to implement this picture.

Can someone show me how to do it please ?
I added a picture because it is difficult to explain exactly what i need[image].

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42493)?

Comment: Thank you for the link, but i need it like on the paper because i want to put it in a pdf.

Comment: Certainly you can learn how to do that from the link that J.M. gave you. You cannot expect us doing your homework for you...