# generating torus and n-torus knots in mathematica

Tags: knots

I am wondering if it's possible to either algorithmically generate or access a built in database of n-torus knots in Mathematica? If not, are there any known databases or algorithms which I could access?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66025? Does that solution do what want?

Comment: I'd like to be able to compute the crossing number and Alexander polynomials, it doesn't seem like this does it, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Have a look at: `KnotData`in the help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion with the KnotData commmand. It doesn't seem like it is possible to generate two-torus, or for this matter n-torus knots. Are there any known methods or commands? Thanks