# How does one plot a Möbius Strip?

Tags: plotting

How can I plot a Möbius strip? I tried [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusStrip.html), but I can't get it to work:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{
    (5 + s*Cos[u/2]) Cos[u],
    (5 + s*Cos[u/2]) Sin[u],
    (s*Sin[u/2])}, {u, -20, 20}, {s, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: my strip]

Comment: Please post the code that you used that didn't work for you. Without the code, it's impossible for us to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: ParametricPlot3D [[[5 + s*Cos[u/2]]*Cos[u], [5 + s*Cos[u/2]]*Sin[u], 
  s*Sin[u/2]], {u, -20, 20}, {s, 0 , 2 \[Pi]}]

@Pickett

Comment: You need at least a space or a * between s and Cos and Sin. There are two instances where you forgot that.

Comment: Just for fun: [Here's](http://community.wolfram.com/c/portal/getImageAttachment?filename=mobius.gif&userId=43903) an animation I made last year.

Comment: See also the attempted solution in the question [Cutting bagels into linked halves](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7545/245).

Comment: How do I make a 3D Mobius strip that will look EXACTLY like the proper (single turn) recycle symbol when viewed from the z-axis? The proper one looks like "Standard" symbol at http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/mathland/recycling_topology.html. What is the 3D formula???

Comment: @user59152 please don't use answers to post questions. Go to the main page and ask it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Equation taken form the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip) page

```
 x[u_, v_] := (1 + (v/2) Cos[u/2]) Cos[u]
 y[u_, v_] := (1 + (v/2) Cos[u/2]) Sin[u]
 z[u_, v_] := (v/2) Sin[u/2]


 plot = ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {v, -1, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Just for fun (using the parametrization from OP hyperlink):

```
mobius[r_, s_,t_] := {r + s Cos[t/2], r + s Cos[t/2], s Sin[t/2]} {Cos[t], Sin[t],
    1}
Manipulate[
 With[{wd = w},
  Row[{
    ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, -wd, wd}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/2, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point@p}, 
     ImageSize -> 200],
    Show[ParametricPlot3D[mobius[r, u, v], {u, -wd, wd}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
       Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Yellow, 
      PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
     Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[mobius[r, ##] & @@ p]}], 
     ImageSize -> 200]
    }]], {r, 1, 2}, {w, 0.5, 2}, {{p, {0, 0}}, {{-w, 0}, {w, 2 Pi}}, 
  Slider2D}]
```

[image]

Comment: computerbasedmath.org, animating math to make it more intuitive.

Answer (score 9):

...and, just for the sake of variation, here is a "minimal" Möbius strip (that is, a [minimal surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalSurface.html) with the topology of a Möbius strip). This example is due to [Meeks](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-81-04829-8).

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(r^3 - 1/r^3) Cos[3 θ]/3 + (r^2 + 1/r^2) Cos[2 θ] + (r - 1/r) Cos[θ],
                  (r^3 - 1/r^3) Sin[3 θ]/3 + (r^2 + 1/r^2) Sin[2 θ] + (r - 1/r) Sin[θ],
                  2 (r - 1/r) Sin[θ]}, {r, 1, 4/3}, {θ, -π, π}]
```

[image: minimal Möbius strip]